# How to set updated apps to System apps?

Tags: android

So i'm gonna be as elaborative as much as I could..

I have a Xperia L with latest firmware and I was trying to set some third party apps to system apps, and I succeeded after some time I thought that if I could set App updates to system app (meaning removing the older version)  and I succeeded again but when I was doing the same to Chrome I stumbled upon to a problem..

So before I tell you what was the problem i'll tell you how I did it..

1.I updated Chrome.
2.I moved the original. apk from "system/app" dir to My SD so that it can be changed to new one. (My set is ROOTED)
3.Then I moved the. apk from "Data/app" folder to "system/app" folder.
4.And renamed it to the Original. apk 's name.
5. And changed the Read/Write Permissions as it should be.
6.That's that.

So after that I tried launching chrome but it said
"Chrome failed to start due to an Unexpected Error"

but with above methods I replaced a lot of apps like Walkman, Calendar, PlayStore, Play Services and some i don't remember...

and they all worked fine even after restarting it..

so then I uninstalled Chrome with Titanium Backup since it was a system app..

and then I tried the same with Album app.

I replaced it's. apk and tried it but it started crashing.. so I deleted it. too and placed the original one back..

and restarted my set..

But now it is stuck on Black Screen after Sony logo...

I know I can Flash the ROM to get going but if there's any other way to do so please let me know..

now i know it's kinda two questions in one but I really need to know both..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: For getting system permission you need add this your AndroidManifest.xml  and you need sign your app  `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system`

Comment: @ylmzekrm1223 I have the permissions but I want to know that why didn't my method didn't work for Chrome and Album app... And why now is it stuck on the Black Screen while Booting?

Comment: The way is to use Titanium Backup PRO..Every thing is there (if anyone is looking for answer or a solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Link2SD or other root apps to add them automatically to the system image